# Making a span unclickable temporarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a simon game, when the series is being shown to the user, I want the span(colored quadrants) to be unclickable. Currently I am employing this function which adds the `pointer-events:none` to the span when it is being animated.

```
 function toggleUnclickable(){
  //unclickable class has the css property pointer-events:none
  $("#1").toggleClass("unclickable");
  $("#2").toggleClass("unclickable");
  $("#3").toggleClass("unclickable");
  $("#4").toggleClass("unclickable");

}
```

I am calling this function before the animation starts and after the animation ends.

```
function animateGeneratedPattern() {

   toggleUnclickable();

  function animateNextPattern(lightup) {
  .... // code for animation
  }
   animateNextPattern(true);
   toggleUnclickable();

}
```

But I am still able to click when the spans are being animated?? Is there something wrong that I am doing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in your elements to enable and disable the click:

```
  $( "#myElement").unbind( "click" ); //disable click
  $( "#myElement").bind( "click" ); //enable
```

Answer (score 1):

onclick=animateNextPattern('your patameter', this) // pass the this keyword here

```
function animateNextPattern(lightup,ele) {
    if(!$(ele).hasClass('unclickable'))  
    {
    Please write your code here ----
    }

     }
```

Comment: wouldnt this animate based on whether its clickable or not ?? If so, that is not what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You can `return true` & `false` to enable/disable click

```
 function toggleclick(bol){
  //unclickable class has the css property pointer-events:none
  $("#1 ,#2,#3,#4").click(function(event) {
            return bol;  
  });
}


function animateGeneratedPattern() {

   toggleUnclickable(false);

  function animateNextPattern(lightup) {
  .... // code for animation
  }
   animateNextPattern(true);
   toggleUnclickable(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use .off() and .on() methods provided by jQuery. whenever you want to unbind the event you can use .off() and then attach it via on()

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#theone", function(){} ) //To attach

$( "body" ).off("click","#theone",function(){}) //To remove
```

More reference can be read over here http://api.jquery.com/off/